# Spring _embedded is not rendering in JPA end points

Tags: spring, jpa

I am new to SPring. I am running an existing Spring application. Previously JPA requests were giving _embedded in the result json. Suddenly the _embedded is not coming in the json. WHy is it so? Is it because of the version of spring. Currently i have spring version as 4.2.0.RC2 and jackson version as 2.6.1 and hateos version as 0.19.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Kindly advise

Comment: Read the tag-descriptions before adding!

Comment: @Olaf - I have @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @OrderColumn(nullable = false)
   public List<OrderItem> cart = new ArrayList<>();   in my model Customer to list the cart items. Previously customers/1/cart has _embedded with orderItems {} But now its not at all showing. Why so. Kindly advise.

Comment: You did not read my comment or did not understand.

Comment: @Olaf You mean the tag descriptions of spring version??

Comment: Sorry didnt understand.